# Tridion 2011 - Filtering XSLT on Formatting Feature window

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion2009

Currently we are doing Tridion upgrade from 2009 to 2011.

I see a strange problem and want to know why it is been updated differently.

### My Problem:

On many of Schema's, we have our own filtering XSLT for content fields (that is, Rich Text Fields).

**Example:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... >
...
...
...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After upgrade to Tridion 2011, I see schema's are updated with the below format

```
<stylesheet... >
...
...
...
</stylesheet>
```

Due to this, on the components rich text fields are not appearing.

> **Please let me know the reason behind this behavior.**

### How to fix this problem?

I have already fixed this solution, below is the fix.

> Replace current XSLT with proper XSLT on Filtering XSLT tab, with the one there on Tridion 2009.

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... >
...
...
...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The prefix is irrelevant as long as the namespace is correct. What was the namespace of the <stylesheet...' element directly after the upgrade?

Comment: @Quirijn: Before upgrade `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">` and after upgrade `<stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`

Comment: In that case it is likely that there was something else that was wrong, because the 'stylesheet' element was in the correct namespace after the upgrade. When you fixed this, did you make any changes other than adding the prefix?

Comment: Presumably if the stylesheet used the default namespace for anything else, this would be a problem.

Comment: Siva - if you are satisfied with your own answer, you should add it as an answer, and accept it. Otherwise this question will continue to show up as unanswered.

Comment: I've just observed this on a system that has never been on 2009.

Comment: I see the same "invisible" namespace on 2013, though fields don't become empty. @Siva, could you share a little more of your original XSLT? Is the namespace prefix the only change?

Answer (score 2):

As you seem to have found yourself - Simply copy and paste your old XSLT from SDL Tridion 2009 over your new one in 2011 (or simply add a default namespace which matches the `xsl` prefix in your original XSLT) . My guess is something went wrong when you migrated your database.