# namespace issue in Tridion 2011 SP1 richtext XSLT with unsupported browser

Tags: xslt, tridion, tridion-2011

I have a richtext field in a schema (Tridion 2011 SP1), with a basic XSLT filter attached (the default XSLT or a custom one, it doesn't matter for this issue).

In IE9, when I create a component based on that schema, the XHTML in the Source tab is rendered fine, without any namespace, e.g.:

```
<p>a paragraph</p>
<p>
    <a href="http://www.sdltridion.com">a link</a>
</p>
```

I am able to save the component.

But in Firefox (16.0.2, unsupported), a namespace is rendered in the Source tab:

```
<p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">a paragraph</p>
<p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <a href="http://www.sdltridion.com">a link</a>
</p>
```

which results in the following XML validation error:

> The element 'Paragraph' in namespace
>   'http://www.yme.com/GeneralContent' has invalid child element 'p' in
>   namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'. List of possible
>   elements expected: any element in namespace
>   'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'..

Now I know that it's an unsupported version of a Firefox, but where is this namespace coming from? The namespace defined in the Richtext XSLT is `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`...

And does anyone know of a possible workaround?

Here's the filtering XSLT, but as I already stated, it happens with the default XSLT too:

```
<stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" cdata-section-elements="script"></output>
    <template match="/ | node() | @*">
        <copy>
            <apply-templates select="node() | @*"></apply-templates>
        </copy>
    </template>
    <template match="*[(self::br or self::p or self::div) and normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos; and not(@*)     and      not(processing-instruction()) and not(comment()) and not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()]) and not(following::node()[not((self::text() or self::br or self::p or self::div) and normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;        and         not(@*) and not(processing-instruction()) and not(comment())        and         not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()]))])]">
    </template>
    <template match="br[parent::div and not(preceding-sibling::node()) and not(following-sibling::node())]">
        <text></text>
    </template>
    <template match="table|td|tr|th|tbody|p|div|a">
        <element name="{name()}">
            <choose>
                <when test="name() =&apos;img&apos;">
                    <for-each select="@*">
                        <attribute name="{name()}">
                            <value-of select="."></value-of>
                        </attribute>
                    </for-each>
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <for-each select="@*">
                        <choose>
                            <when test="name() =&apos;border&apos;"></when>
                            <when test="name() =&apos;cellpadding&apos;"></when>
                            <when test="name() =&apos;cellspacing&apos;"></when>
                            <when test="name() =&apos;bgcolor&apos;"></when>
                            <when test="name() =&apos;bordercolor&apos;"></when>
                            <when test="name() =&apos;width&apos;"></when>
                            <when test="name() =&apos;height&apos;"></when>
                            <when test="name() =&apos;bordercolor&apos;"></when>
                            <when test="name() =&apos;span&apos;"></when>
                            <when test="name() =&apos;style&apos;"></when>
                            <when test="name() =&apos;class&apos;">
                                <choose>
                                    <when test=". =&apos;MsoNormal&apos;"></when>
                                    <otherwise>
                                        <attribute name="{name()}">
                                            <value-of select="."></value-of>
                                        </attribute>
                                    </otherwise>
                                </choose>
                            </when>
                            <otherwise>
                                <attribute name="{name()}">
                                    <value-of select="."></value-of>
                                </attribute>
                            </otherwise>
                        </choose>
                    </for-each>
                </otherwise>
            </choose>
            <apply-templates></apply-templates>
        </element>
    </template>
    <template match="h1">
        <element name="h2">
            <apply-templates></apply-templates>
        </element>
    </template>
    <template match="td/p">
        <apply-templates></apply-templates>
    </template>
    <template match="li/p">
        <apply-templates></apply-templates>
    </template>
    <template match="link|script|font|iframe|ilayer|layer|span|small">
        <apply-templates></apply-templates>
    </template>
</stylesheet>
```

Comment: Has your environment been recently migrated to 2011? If so can you post your Format Area XSLT in the question?

Comment: Yes, it has been migrated from 2009. We already had to fix another issue with richtext XSLT (Source tab would stay blank when switching). 
I added the filtering XSLT, but this happens with the default XSLT too. I'm wondering whether changes like these are really persistent in cache? I restarted IIS anyway after restoring the default XSLT

Comment: You might need to delete your browser cache to see the changes, as the Schema is cached locally on the client browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this issue is related to this post

[Tridion 2011 - Filtering XSLT on Formatting Feature window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219267/tridion-2011-filtering-xslt-on-formatting-feature-window)

It seems like the migration process (or perhaps an odd GUI behavior) is altering the filtering XSLT, and seems to impact the behavior of the RTF fields. Basically the way the namespace and namespace prefixes  are used in the XSLT seem to have changed. A typical XSLT uses the `xsl` namespace prefix, wheras your new XSLT seems to exclude the prefix and use a default namespace.

I think this is a bug, and should be submitted to support, but the workaround is covered in the related post.

Comment: Indeed - the "html" elements in a Format Area are in the xhtml namespace, so it makes sense for the default namespace in the XSLT to match that, so that you can write <p> when you mean <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">. It's very normal on the other hand to use an explicit namespace prefix for XSL elements. Somehow the XSLT now has the wrong default namespace, and all they symptoms follow on logically from there. +1

Comment: So, should component sources have the namespace (e.g. `<p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">a paragraph</p>`)?

Answer (score 3):

Well your stylesheet has `<stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">` and then does `<element name="{name()}">` for `<template match="table|td|tr|th|tbody|p|div|a">` meaning it takes input `p` (and `table` etc.) elements and transforms them into elements with the same name (e.g. `p`) but in the XSLT namespace.

So what you probably want instead is write the XSLT code with a prefix (i.e. `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">` and `<xsl:template match="table|td|tr|th|tbody|p|div|a">`) so that the XSLT namespace does not interfere with result elements you want to create.

On the other hand replacing  `<element name="{name()}">` with `<xsl:copy>` should do as well.

Comment: +1, the xsl prefix is stripped off somehow when saving, so no use putting it in. Removing this part of the template does solve it, but as Chris stated, I think this is a bug